# Prevent build artifacts from going into revision control

Tags: git, heroku, version-control, gitignore

I am currently following this heroku tutorial , try to build something and put on heroku cloud server. but i am struggling on this point ->

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#gitignore

how do I create `.gitignore`   and prevent build artifact from going into revision control?
how do I do it exactly?
can anyone give some help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `.gitignore` files

The `.gitignore` file is just a regular file like any other. Your link suggests ignoring `target`. If that is the only thing you want to ignore, simply create a new file called `.gitignore` in the root of your repository that contains

```
target
```

then `git add .gitignore` and commit.

### gitignore.io

I like to use [gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io/) as a base when creating a new ignore file. They suggest the following `.gitignore` for working with Java:

```
# Created by http://www.gitignore.io

### Java ###
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
```